# Why do Sun keyboards use diamond for meta?

Tags: keyboards, sun-workstation

The Sun Type 3 keyboard labelled its meta keys "Left" and "Right".  The Type 4 changed this to a hollow diamond, or lozenge: ◇.  The Type 5 and on uses a solid diamond: ◆.

My question is: why use the diamond symbol for meta?

Comment: I suppose because the SUN logo is diamond shaped?

Comment: Further to Patrick's guess, notice that Sun adopted the Apple Desktop Bus and, at least for a period, Apple used much the same markings on its keyboards — albeit with a filled or hollow Apple logo rather than a diamond.

Comment: How old need I to be to know what is a meta key?

Comment: @DanubianSailor old enough to read, I guess. E.g. [this page](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_Keycode) contains a reference to it in the current SDL documentation. It's an ongoing term. See also: [xmodmap](https://www.in-ulm.de/~mascheck/X11/xmodmap.html).

Comment: This question is so meta. If anyone needs me, I'll be in my open apple, taking control of my windows as I shift their command structure for my upcoming space cadet induction.

Comment: @DanubianSailor, as a sailor you should know the meta key comes from SAIL, the Stanford AI laboratory.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

To elevate Patrick Schlüter's comment into an answer: here's a picture of one of Sun's keyboards:

[image]

Compare and contrast with one of Apple's keyboards:

[image]

Or even with a modern Microsoft keyboard:

[image]

Sun's diamond symbols sit where Apple uses the Apple logo and Microsoft uses the Windows logo; it's therefore a safe bet that they reference Sun's diamond logo as shown on the top right of the pictured keyboard.

Comment: I don't think they used ADB: Sun keyboards had an 8-pin connector that wasn't compatible with Apple's 6-pin ADB port. That's a Sun Type 6 keyboard from ~1997→, while the Apple keyboard is quite a bit older

Comment: That’s a Sun keyboard from the period in which Sun used ADB.

Comment: Please provide links that show that Sun used ADB; I can find none. I was a Sun admin for a few years, and for a while managed a mixed Sun/Apple shop. The keyboard interfaces were very different. Sun used a TTL 1200 baud serial protocol supporting two devices, which ADB had commands and addresses and was (in theory) much faster

Comment: @scruss Sun had to my knowledge licenced ADB from apple (together with some other stuff, they were rather close around 1985). There have been prototypes for using ADB with SUN, but they never materialized in regular products.

Comment: Tommy, I think the sequence is rather the other way around. Apple introduced the Open/Closed Apple for the Apple III (1980), and later moved it to the Apple IIe (1983). Inbetween was the Lisa with a single Apple key. When the Mac came it was replaced by command as Jobs thought putting the key combinations as Apple+letter in menues would produce too many logos on screen. Mid 80s the IIgs came with ADB - later to be added to the Mac SE - so there were keyboards with Command and Open/Closed Apple. Which is incidentally the time Apple and sun were close and the 3/180 introduced the Type 4 Keyboard

Comment: The rest is history: With the demise of the Apple II line the Open/Closed Apple keys vanished - right at the time MS introduced the Windows key for their new keyboards ...

Comment: Have removed ADB from the answer, since I don't think it's actually an issue of substance. @scruss I typed 'apple desktop bus +sun' into a search engine. [Here's the very first link](https://www.techopedia.com/definition/293/apple-desktop-bus-adb). From that page: "The ADB was also used on various systems that used a 680x0-base microcomputer such as NeXT, Hewlett Packard (HP) and Sun Microsystems."

Comment: To put it on the table up front, since I've visited this site before, given that: (i) the answer no longer references ADB, and (ii) a source has been provided re: Sun/ADB; I think our choices are now ever decreasing circles of "but I _know_ this, your references must be wrong" versus "I believe this, because here's another reference", or just putting it aside and moving on. I vote the latter.

Comment: @PatrickSchlüter and Tommy, your argument seems strong.  I will accept this as a likely explanation.